# Left and Right Cosets of a Subgroup of Index 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that if $H$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in a finite group $G$, then every left coset of $H$ is also a right coset of $H$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$H$ is a coset, and the only other possible coset is $G \setminus H$ by order considerations.

Comment: How do we know that $G$ \ $H$ is both a left and right coset?

Comment: The set of left cosets is $\{G, G \setminus H\}$ and the set of right cosets is $\{G, G \setminus H\}$